# Finding a specific Cell

Tags: r

I know this is a quite simple question, but I have not found a solution so far (newish to R).

I have a blob of data in a text file and get it via the following function:

```
path <- "filepath"
print(path)

conn <- file(path,open="r")
lines <- readLines(conn)
zzzz <- data.frame(Text=rep(NA,length(lines)))
for (i in 1:length(lines)){
  zzzz[i,] <- lines[i]
}
close(conn)
```

This results, that I have a table with exactly one column and `i` rows. In this table I need to search for the first cell (including to know, which cell it is), which contains the following text:

```
#&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Zeit&n
```

I tried it with `grep`, `grepl`, `match`, `which`, `subset` and some other stuff but I never got the specific cell, where this term first shows up.

So, the desired goal:

-Know the specific cell, where the term (see above) first shows up

Reason is, after I find the specific cell I need to format the cell and the following 100 rows into a single `string`, so that the remaining analysis works properly (and yes, I know this is clunky but the only way I found that the whole damn thing works at all >.> )

Hope you can help me out!

Comment: `match("#&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Zeit&n", zzzz$Text)` ?

Comment: `grep("#&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Zeit&n", lines)` works with made up data.

Comment: @ Rui, if I am correct `grep()` gives all rows of `#&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Zeit&n`, and OP only needs the 1st?

Comment: the `match` one doesn't work, the `grep` one somewhat does. It gives all lines but I should be able to extract the first one out of there.

Comment: `which(zzzz == "yourstring", arr.ind = TRUE)` should also work.

Comment: the `which` one doesn't work (had the exact same thought at first), but I have no idea why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rui Barradas, got the answer I needed:

`grep("#&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Zeit&n", lines)`

to be exact, I adapted it into this to get onyl the first result:

`vek <- min(grep("#&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Zeit&n", lines))`

For the creation of the string I did the following (works perfectly):

`tttt <- paste(zzzz[vek:(vek+100),], collapse ='')`

Edit says: `which` doesn't work when there is additonal text in the cell than just the searched term (it looks exactly for that cell, where exactly that term is in there and nothing else)

Answer (score 0):

Make data.frame with:

```
 df=data.frame(x=c("sdhaisdh","#&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Zeit&n",'ASfjdfbgvfdvfd',"sadashdh","#&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Zeit&n","832yhf",rep("sadwd",times=100)))
```

Find first cell with our condition:

```
  num=which(grepl("#&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Zeit&n",df$x))[1]
```

Make `string` for 100 next rows:

```
glue::collapse(df[num:(num+100),"x"],"")
```